# get progress of downloaded file with file's size in a custom header in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have an endpoint that let me download a zip file in my swift app. But the problem is that the endpoint send me the file's size in a custom header not in content-length because it uses the Transfer-Encoding: chunked. I am using alamofire to manage the request but the library uses by default the content-length header to track the progresse. 
is there a solution to track the progress with a custom header in alamofire and if not how to use the custom header to track the progress and show it in a progress view. 
thank you guys for the help ! 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this, and no way at all to do it for a download to file. For data transfers, at a high level what you'd need to do is:

1. Implement the `urlSession(_:dataTask:didReceive:completionHandler:)` delegate method to listen for the initial `URLResponse` your request receives.
2. Once the response is stored, in the `urlSession(_:dataTask:didReceive:)` method that tracks the `Data` you're receiving as it's downloaded, updating any progress with the total data downloaded vs. the value in the `Len` header.

This would require modifications to Alamofire itself which, while possible, would be involved. If at all possible, seeing if the endpoint can return a `Content-Length` header instead would be much better.

Comment: Clear answer Thank you @John for your help I will see with the backend developper if he can add the content length header first

Comment: Having looked it up, since the `chunked` `Transfer-Encoding` setting specifically omits the `Content-Length` header, I'm not sure whether manually adding it would let it be picked up automatically by the underlying networking system. If you can, moving away from `chunked` encoding entirely would probably be a better idea, especially since it's completely incompatible with HTTP/2.